# Unity UI text appears properly in game view, but not in build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I'm receiving data over a UDP connection, which I've displayed as UI text. Now this works fine in game view whereas when i build and run it, the text shows **but not the values**. I've attached images below.

[Game view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFfgT.jpg) - [Build view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqCMr.jpg)

I've set this up by:

```
[SerializeField]
Text testing;

public string text2 = "";
```

I then referenced the UI text object in this function:

```
public void OnGUI()
{
    //other stuff for this function

    testing = GetComponent<Text>();
    testing.text = "altitude:" + text2;
}
```

And in the receiving data function where I define what I want the text to be:

```
    void ReceiveData()
{

    client = new UdpClient(port);
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            // Bytes received.
            IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            data = client.Receive(ref anyIP);
            var dest = data.Skip(21).Take(4).ToArray();

            //converting bytes to string
            float value = BitConverter.ToSingle(dest, 0);
            string text = value.ToString();
            text2 = text;
            // print text
            print(">> " + text)
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            print(err.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general: You should **not** use `OnGUI`! It is kind of legacy and was way back replaced by the UI System you are already using anyway.

If you want something to happen every frame rather use [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html)

---

I assume (hope) the UdP runs in a background thread. I would use a pattern often called "Main thread dispatcher":

- Have a [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1) or [`ConcurrentStack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentstack-1) (depending on your needs) which are **thread save**
- from any thread add new items to it via [`Enqueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1.enqueue#System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentQueue_1_Enqueue__0_)(queue) or [`Push`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentstack-1.push#System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentStack_1_Push__0_)(stack)
- In the Unity **main thread** have a worker that uses [`TryDequeue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1.trydequeue#System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentQueue_1_TryDequeue__0__)(queue) to receive and remove the first item, or [`TryPop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentstack-1.trypop#System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentStack_1_TryPop__0__)(stack) to receive and remove the last item

  -> execute in the main thread

---

You can either go with the [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1) (first-in first-out)

```
private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> actions = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

private void Update()
{
    while(actions.TryDequeue(out var Action)
    {
        action?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

in this case you want to work off **all** actions that got appended to the  queue since the last frame. You would add the according action from your UDP thread like

```
    ...

    float value = BitConverter.ToSingle(dest, 0);
    string text = value.ToString();

    actions.Enqueue(() => 
    {
        text2 = text;
        // print text
        print(">> " + text);
    }
}
catch(Exception err
{
    actions.Enqueue(() => print(err.ToString());
}
```

---

Or in your case you can even optimize it a bit and save some work/resources: Only use and display the **last** received string instead so you can use the [`ConcurrentStack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentstack-1) (last-in first-out)

```
private readonly ConcurrentStack<string> receivedStrings = new ConcurrentStack<string>();

private void Update()
{
    if(receivedStrings.TryPop(out var message))
    {
        text2 = message;
        print(">> " + message);

        // dump all previous messages
        receivedStrings.Clear();
    }
}
```

and you would then only add the received messages to the stack like

```
...

 float value = BitConverter.ToSingle(dest, 0);
 string text = value.ToString();

 receivedStrings.Push(text);
```

---

As for your comment about multiple text components:

Yes you can use multiple `ConcurrentStack`. I would then use them like this:

```
// First define the IDs you want to use
private enum StackID
{
    Text1,
    Text2,
    Text3,
    ...
}

// Reference your individual Text components via the Inspector
[SerializeField] private Text _text1;
[SerializeField] private Text _text2;
[SerializeField] private Text _text3;
...

// The special string you use for splitting the receivedessage
// configure via the Inspector
[SerializeField] private string _splitter = "$$";

// This holds all ConcurrentStack addressed by their StackID
private Dictionary<StackID, ConcurrentStack<string>> _stacks = new Dictionary<StackID, ConcurrentStack<string>>();

// This links the given Text components to a certain StackID
// in other words which text shall listen to which stack
private Dictionary<StackID, Text> _texts = new Dictionary<StackID, Text>();

private void Awake ()
{
    // Initialize the dictionaries
    foreach(var id in (StackID[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(StackID)))
    {
        _stacks.Add(id, new ConcurrentStack<string>());
    }

    _texts.Add(StackID.Text1, _text1);
    _texts.Add(StackID.Text2, _text2);
    _texts.Add(StackID.Text3, _text3);
    ...
}

private void Start ()
{
    // start the Receiver
    var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveData));
    thread.Start();
}

private void Update ()
{
    // Iterate through all values of StackID
    foreach(var id in (StackID[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(StackID)))
    {
        if(_stacks[id].TryPop(out var message))
        {
            _texts[id].text = message;
            print(">> " + message);

            // dump all previous messages
            _stacks[id].Clear();
        }
    }
}

// On Background Thread
void ReceiveData()
{
    client = new UdpClient(port);
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            // Bytes received.
            IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            data = client.Receive(ref anyIP);

            //converting bytes to string
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

            // Now split the message into your parts and pass them into the individual stacks
            var texts = message.Split(new string[]{ _splitter }, message);

            _stacks[StackID.Text1]. Enqueue(texts[0]);
            _stacks[StackID.Text2]. Enqueue(texts[1]);
            _stacks[StackID.Text3]. Enqueue(texts[2]);
            ...
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            foreach(var id in (StackID[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(StackID)))
            {
                _stacks[id].Enqueue(err.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: thank you for the answer. I've been using the ConcurrentStack method and it works but for future reference, if I wanted to use more than one string would it be a good idea to use more than one ConcurrentStack? 

So in the example there's text2, and then you could have text3 and text4 which you push to other stacks (receivedStrings3 and receivedStrings4).

Comment: @Dully737 this always depends on your usecase. In general I would have one single stack foreach udp/tcp receiver. If however you also need to `string.Split` the received messages I would as you describe do the splitting while still on the background thread and use multiple `ConcurrentStack` foreach text component. There is nothing bad about it. In order to keep things clean in the code I would then maybe use a `Dictionary<someEnum, ConcurrentStack<string>>` so this one Dictionary holds the references to all your stacks and all you have to do is add id entries to the enum

Comment: See Update at the bottom. I'm only on the phone so I didn't test it but I think this should work